# What does "one" refer to in "one pushing the other"? Does it refer to the girls or to the cars?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, translation

In the sentence below, what does "one" refer to in "one pushing the other"? Does it refer to the girls or to the cars?

> On the way into town one day I noticed a couple of young girls working their way along the lines of cars waiting at a busy junction, one pushing the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English, the phrase *"one pushing the other"* can only refer to two things, the *"one"* and *"the other"*. If there were more than two things, the phrasing should have been *"the others"* or *"pushing one another"*. Thus, it cannot refer to the lines of cars, which clearly contain a lot more than two cars.

It must be that one of the girls was pushing the other, although it's not entirely clear how (maybe in a wheelchair; maybe not).

Answer (score -1):

> On the way into town one day, I noticed a couple of young girls working their way along the lines of cars [which were] waiting at a busy junction, one pushing the other.

This is perhaps a little ambiguous. In general, I would assume that the clause relates to the most recent subject in the sentence, unless there is a reason to think otherwise. Therefore I would assume that the cars were pushing one-another.

A reason you may read it the other way, is if there was some punctuation as follows:

I noticed a couple of young girls **, who were working their way along the lines of cars waiting at a busy junction,** one pushing the other.

Answer (score -2):

> on the way into town one day I noticed a couple of young girls working their way along the lines of cars waiting at a busy junction, one pushing the other.

One girl is pushing the other girl.  As we know nothing else about the girls, "one" just means one of the girls -- the one pushing.